# Imputing null values for metrics used as features in ML model

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering

I have a data set from a live application. Each row is a user interacting with the app. We are predicting a feature for which we currently have a deterministic solution for. There is ample training data and labeled data for what happened vs what we predicted in the deterministic case.

A number of in the moment metrics for the moments prior to the *ith* customer interaction are relevant for this *ith* customer. However, some metrics like avg of event X in the past hour (say avg $ value of transactions of type X in past hour) can be null because the division is by zero (0 events of that type occurring). How should this feature be handled/imputed in the training data. I’m not sure if using the median or using KNN is such a good idea in this case, I don’t want to drop the observations (will lose 20-30% of training samples across the feature set). Would it make sense to impute it to 0 in this instance. In most of these metrics a high number implies a busy system and a low number implies it’s relatively manageable.

In production application of this model, how would calculating the median be done (if that is still the best option) - keep a sizable sample median handy in memory and recalculate at some interval for each feature that might need imputing using the median? It would be way too slow and expensive to trigger Spark jobs to compute in real-time, as there are millions of times we’d call the ML model for this prediction.